# How to cancel old staging pipeline when a new push is made to the staging branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following pipeline:

```
trigger:
- staging
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  pnpm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pnpm-store

stages:
  - stage: "Build"
    jobs:
      - job: build
        steps:
          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'pnpm | "$(Agent.OS)" | pnpm-lock.yaml'
              path: $(pnpm_config_cache)
            displayName: Cache pnpm

          - script: |
              corepack enable
              corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
              pnpm config set store-dir $(pnpm_config_cache)
            displayName: "Setup pnpm"

          - script: |
              pnpm install
              pnpm run build
            displayName: "pnpm install and build"

          - publish: 'dist'
            artifact: drop

  - stage: "Staging"
    condition: |
      and (succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'staging'))
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      environment: staging
      variables:
      - group: Release
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop
            - task: AzureWebApp@1
              displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
                appType: "webApp"
                appName: '$(FEAppNameStaging)'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'

  - stage: "Production"
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      environment: production
      variables:
      - group: Release
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop
            - task: AzureWebApp@1
              displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: 'MySubscription'
                appType: "webApp"
                appName: '$(FEAppNameProduction)'
```

When I push to the staging branch, the pipeline builds the code, deploys to staging and then waits for manual approval until it deploys to production. If I let's say find an error and make another push to fix the error, another pipeline starts and now I have two pipelines waiting for approval:
[The pipeline runs then look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQYmf.png)

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

I was thinking about using a timeout, but that is not ideal, as the testing stage doesn't have a specific time frame and I'd find having to rerun the pipeline for another deploy a worse solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I can understand you would expect the pre-existing stage pending approval to be rejected or cancelled automatically as soon as the same pipeline is triggered by a new commit.

For a release pipeline, we can leverage the feature of [Deploy latest and cancel the others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#specify-queuing-policies); however, it is not possible for a YAML pipeline at the moment as explained in the document that

> YAML pipelines don't support queuing policies. Each run of a pipeline is independent from and unaware of other runs. In other words, your two successive commits may trigger two pipelines, and both of them will execute the same sequence of stages without waiting for each other. While we work to bring queuing policies to YAML pipelines, we recommend that you use manual approvals in order to manually sequence and control the order the execution if this is of importance.

Hope the information would help.